# Best method for comparing XML with string

Tags: c#, xml

I am looking for the best way to compare XML data with a string. 
the data is stored in a xml called test.xml, and must be compared with the name descendant, if there is a match more info from the xml must be added to a textbox and picture box.

My ( working ) code:

```
        var xmlDocument = XDocument.Load("test.xml");               // XML koppellen
        var key1 = xmlDocument.Descendants("NAME");                 // XML filepath
        var key2 = xmlDocument.Descendants("TITLE");                // XML titel
        var key3 = xmlDocument.Descendants("BRAND");                // XML afbeelding
        var key4 = xmlDocument.Descendants("TYPE");                 // XML merk
        var key5 = xmlDocument.Descendants("SOORT");                // XML type
        var key6 = xmlDocument.Descendants("NAAM");                 // XML naam

        List<string> file = new List<string>();
        List<string> title = new List<string>();
        List<string> brand = new List<string>();
        List<string> type = new List<string>();
        List<string> soort = new List<string>();
        List<string> naam = new List<string>();

        int i = 0;

        foreach (var key in key1)
        {
            file.Add(key.Value.Trim());
        }

        foreach (var key in key2)
        {
            title.Add(key.Value.Trim());
        }

        foreach (var key in key3)
        {
            brand.Add(key.Value.Trim());
        }

        foreach (var key in key4)
        {
            type.Add(key.Value.Trim());
        }

        foreach (var key in key5)
        {
            soort.Add(key.Value.Trim());
        }

        foreach (var key in key6)
        {
            naam.Add(key.Value.Trim());
        }


        foreach (var Name in naam)
        {
            if (textBox3.Text.ToString() == Name.ToString())
            {
                PDFLocation = file[i].ToString();
                pictureBox1.Image = pdfhandler.GetPDFthumbNail(PDFLocation);
                textBox4.Text =
                                title[i].ToString() + "\r\n" +
                                brand[i].ToString() + "\r\n" +
                                type[i].ToString() + "\r\n" +
                                soort[i].ToString() + "\r\n" +
                                textBox3.Text + "\r\n";
            }
            i++;
        }
```

]

I think this is not the best way to do it, but cant see a better way....

Update: solution:

```
        foreach (XElement element in xmlDocument.Descendants("PDFDATA"))
        {
            if (textBox3.Text.ToString() == element.Element("NAAM").Value.Trim())
                {

                    PDFLocation = element.Element("NAME").Value.ToString();
                    pictureBox1.Image = pdfhandler.GetPDFthumbNail(PDFLocation);
                    textBox4.Text =
                                    element.Element("TITLE").Value + "\r\n" +
                                    element.Element("BRAND").Value + "\r\n";
                    break;

                }
        }
```

Comment: what you need is a class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of thinking of the xml and a bunch of individual lists of data, it helps to think of it more as objects. Then you can loop through each element one at a time and don't need to split it up into individual lists. This not only removes duplicate code but more importantly creates a better abstraction of the data you are working with. This makes it easier to read and understand what the code is doing.

```
foreach (XElement element in xmlDocument.Elements())
{
    if (textBox3.Text.ToString() == element.Element("NAAM").Value)
    {
        PDFLocation = element.Element("NAAM").Value;
        pictureBox1.Image = pdfhandler.GetPDFthumbNail(PDFLocation);
        textBox4.Text =
                        element.Element("Title").Value + "\r\n" +
                        element.Element("Brand").Value + "\r\n" +
                        element.Element("Type").Value + "\r\n"
                        // access rest of properties...
    }
}
```

Comment: this code will throw exception in the first iteration.

Comment: @Selman22 This isn't intended as working production code with unit tests included...It's merely an example of how you can loop through whole Elements and access their properties instead of splitting them into individual lists. SO isn't about writing somebody's code for them so they can just copy and paste it, compile and move on to the next problem.